# Create Global HTTPS load-balancer with gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, gcloud

I haven't kept up with changes to GCP's load-balancing, and they've introduced a new kind of global L7 load-balancer, and the ones which I am used to are now termed "classic".

I am not able to find ways to create these new style of load-balancers using `gcloud` CLI. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You use the same commands except for changing one option: `--load-balancing-scheme=LOAD_BALANCING_SCHEME`  (EXTERNAL_MANAGED versus EXTERNAL) https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/create#--load-balancing-scheme The classic load balancer is the default The new load balancer is based on Envoy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to mark the question answered, I will post @John_Hanley's reply here:

Set the flag like this:

`gcloud gcloud compute backend-services create --load-balancing-scheme=EXTERNAL_MANAGED`